# Composite primary key in many-to-many relationship and column in code first

Tags: many-to-many, ef-code-first, data-annotations, fluent-interface

I guess this is covered somewhere but I'm not able to find. Guess I'm not using the correct search terms.

Basically I have a Many-to-Many table that I define as POCO. You could then also look at it as a table with two one-to-many relations if you wish.

On one end there is a user table and a division table on the other end. However each user-division combo can have several relations, one for each year. So in the associate table there will be a int column for year and the Primary key will be composite from UserId fk, DivisionId fk and Year.

I wasn't sure how to do this in EF 4.1 Code First. I'm hoping there is a DataAnnotation way and a FluentApi way.

If you could point me towards a tutorial that covers this I would really be happy.

User:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    //some other properties

    public virtual ICollection<DivisionService> Services { get; set; }
}
```

Division:

```
public class Division
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int DivisionId { get; set; }

    //some other properties

    public virtual ICollection<DivisionService> Services { get; set; }
}
```

Join/Main table:

```
public class DivisionService
{
    public int Year { get; set; }  //this and the two foreign keys should be composite Primary Key

    //some other properties

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Division Division { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [HasKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671266%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method in FluentAPI and call `.HasKey(x => new { x.Year, x.UserId, x.DivisionId })`. With data annotations simply specify the `[Key]` attribute on these three properties.

Comment: I can add [Key] to the User and Division properties and EF understands that as the fk to that table?

Comment: No, the `[Key]` is about PK. If you wanna to use the join table with Year, you have to set up the association as two 1-N or have the year part of PK. There's no support for associations with payload.

Comment: Well that's what I am talking about. You said I should put the [Key] attribute on UserId and DivisionId as in the foreign keys in DivisionService, but I do not define them, code first does that for me. So could I put them on the properties and Code First understands that as the FK fields?

Comment: No. It's a key, so it needs to be there.

Comment: OK we are not on the same wavelength here. If you would just copy my code sample for DivisionService from the question and insert the [Key] attribute where it should be I think we could sort this out :)

Comment: You need to add columns you mentioned before XxxId ... Without these you'll not be able to create (proper) new entity.

Comment: So I need to add the foreign keys myself. Does Code First automatically understand that they are the foreignKeys to those entries or will I have to mark them as such with some attribute?

Comment: Yes, because it's PK&FK together, it's a join table. If the property name is going to match at least one convention then it will. Else you have to use attributes or FluentAPI.